# Which output activation and loss should I use if I want to predict continuous outcome on 0-1 interval?

Tags: keras, autoencoder, loss-function, continuous, activation-function

I want to predict continuous variable (autoencoder). As I have scaled my inputs by min-max to 0-1 interval, does it make sense to use sigmoid activation in output layer? Sigmoid does not correspond to MSE loss then. Any ideas?

Comment: Sigmoid with binary crossentropy is usually a good option. You can always use MSE too, no problem.

Comment: binary cross entropy is used for the binary outcome, it has its meaning. However, I want to predict continuous variable, not binary.

Comment: I see.... Although in a neural network, everything is continous, of course. Using a binary crossentropy wouldn't be "wrong". It may behave in a different way indeed (see OverLord's answer), but the point of minimum loss will be your desired output, as with other losses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SUMMARY:**  if unsure, go with `binary_crossentropy` + `sigmoid`. If most your labels are 0's or 1's, or very close to, try `mae` + `hard_sigmoid`.

---

**EXPLANATION**:

Loss functions define a model's priorities; for regression, the goal's to *minimize deviation* of predictions from ground truth (labels). With an activation bounded between 0 and 1, MSE will work.

*However*; it may not be best - in particular, for normalized data. Below is a plot of MSE vs MAE for the [0, 1] interval. Key differences:

- **MSE** penalizes small differences *much less* than MAE
- **MSE** penalizes large differences, w.r.t. *its own penalties* of small values, much more than MAE

As a consequence of above:

- **MSE** --> model is better at not being 'very wrong', but worse at being 'very right'
- **MAE** --> model is better at predicting all values on average, but doesn't mind 'very wrong' predictions

As far as activations go - *hard sigmoid* may work better, especially if many of your values are equal to or very close to 0 or 1, as it can equal 0 or 1 (or approach them) a lot quicker than sigmoid can, which should serve as a form of *regularization*, since it *is* a form of *linearization* (--> weight decay).

---

**Binary crossentropy**: should generally work the best (w/ *sigmoid*)

In a sense, it's the best of both worlds: it's more 'evenly distributed' (over non-asymptotic interval), and strongly penalizes 'very wrong' predictions. In fact, BCE is much harsher on such predictions than MSE - so you should rarely if ever see a "0" predicted on a "1" label (except in validation). Just be sure *not* to use hard sigmoid, for self-evident reasons.

---

**Autoencoders**: strive to reconstruct their input. Depending on the application, you may:

1. Need to ensure that *no single prediction bears too much significance*. *Ex*: signal data. A single extremely wrong timestep could outweigh an otherwise excellent overall reconstruction
2. Have noisy data, and prefer a model more *robust to noise*

Per both above, especially (1), BCE may be undesirable. By treating all labels more 'equally', MAE may work better for (2).

---

**MSE vs. MAE**:

[image]

**Sigmoid vs. Hard Sigmoid**

[image]

---

**Binary crossentropy vs. MSE vs. MAE** (`y == 0` case shown for BCE)

[image]

Comment: No, you cannot blindly recommend binary cross-entropy, its a classification loss, and here the problem is clearly a regression problem (continuous outputs).

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro It holds for regression "on 0-1 interval", directly quoting the title.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sigmoid` activation and a regression loss such as `mean_squared_error` or `mean_absolute_error`